# File path is not being saved in SQL database

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am having trouble saving the file path to a document in my SQL database. I need to save it so I can then retrieve the file at a later stage.

So basically what the app does is that it continuously watching a specific folder for any changes. So when a file is added it detects it and then should save that file in the database. Now I am not sure what the best practice here is to save the file or just the file path?

This is the code I currently testing with:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "C:\\Documents";
    MonitorDirectory(path);
    Console.ReadKey();
} 

private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
{
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
    fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
    fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
    fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);

    string connectionString = @"Data Source=Development-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=FileDB;Integrated Security=True";
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
    byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    reader.Close();
    stream.Close();
    DateTime dateTimeVariable = DateTime.Now;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable (filename, datestamp) VALUES (@filename, 
    @datestamp)", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.Binary, file.Length).Value = file;
    command.Parameters.Add("@datestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime, file.Length).Value = 
    dateTimeVariable;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The error I am getting is at Line 42:

```cs
command.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.Binary, file.Length).Value = file;
```

Which is:

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You need to debug the code and check if `file` is null or not.

Comment: file is definitely null

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code. You store the `FileSystemWatcher` in a local variable, so it can be garbage collected at any time. You open the file for `ReadWrite` even though you only need read. You do not put `using` around any of the disposable objects (`stream`, `reader`, `command`, `connection`). You store file contents in a field called filename. You provide a length for the datetime parameter. You don't resort to your [basic debug skills](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254094/11683) because the debugger will tell you what is `null` on the line 42.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response!  I am relatively new to this as I generally do more in HTML.   Is there  a tutorial I can follow to help me achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GSerg is correct, there are lot of problems with your code.  You don't have to read the file if you just need the file name.  `FileInfo` can provide you with that information.  If you need to read the content and save it you will need a filecontent field in your db.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Documents";
        MonitorDirectory(path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Development-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FileDB;Integrated Security=True";
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        byte[] file;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(e.FullPath))
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            file = reader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);
        }
        //FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        //BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        //byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        //reader.Close();
        //stream.Close();
        DateTime dateTimeVariable = DateTime.Now;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable (filename, datestamp) VALUES (@filename,  @datestamp)", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = info.Name;
                command.Parameters.Add("@filecontent", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = file;
                command.Parameters.Add("@datestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimeVariable;
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are not closing the SqlConnection

Comment: Awesome Thanks,  Its working now.  Its save it correctly now.  So I guess I will be able to retrieve that document now?

Comment: If I want to or need to?

Comment: Why are you reading from the file if you just need the filename ? And filename will not be sufficient because you need the complete path

Comment: And you are still not disposing the SqlConnection :-)